# What is the smallest positive integer $n$, such that there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What is the smallest positive integer $n$, such that there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$, with $b$ obtained from $a$ by a rearrangement of its digits, so that
>   $a – b = 11\dots 1$ (The number of '$1$'s equal to $n$)?

Is there any example that can satisfy the equation?

Answer (score 5):

Hint 1. Since $b$ is obtained as a rearrangement of the digits of $a$, it follows that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when they are divided by $9$. Hence $a-b$ should be divisible by $9$.

Hint 2. Note that
$$90-09=81,\ 190-019=171,\ 1290-0129=1161,\ 12390-01239=11151, \dots$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $b = \text{DigitsRearranged}(a) \rightarrow$ $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $9$ $\rightarrow$ $a-b$ is divisible by $9$ $\rightarrow$ $n \ge 9$

And this is sufficient, because there is a solution for this $n$:
$$a = 812,345,709 \\
b = 701,234,598 \\
a-b = 111,111,111$$

So the smallest $n$ is: $n = 9$.

This took a fair bit a fiddling around to find, toguh.